# this.validator is not a function with formarray. Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, formarray

I'm working on a page which has a nested Formarray.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.buildForm();
  }

  private buildForm() {
    this.trialBudgetForm = this.fb.group({
        clients: this.fb.array([])
    })
  }
  addCustomer() {
    this.clients.push(this.initCustomer());
  }
  initCustomer() {
    return this.fb.group({
      earnedIncomes: this.fb.array([this.initIncome()]),
      thirtyAndOneThirdYN: [],
      thirtyYN: [],
      earnedIncomeExpenseType: [],
      earnedIncomeExpense: [],
      dependentCareExpense: []
    })
  }
  initIncome() {
     return this.fb.group(new ScrAmountType());
  }
   ngOnInit() {
      this.populateData();
   }
  populateData() {
     const clients = this.TrialBudgetData.clients;
     const customerFGs = clients.map(customer => this.fb.group({
     earnedIncomes: this.populateIncome(customer.earnedIncomes),
     thirtyAndOneThirdYN: [this.utilService.YNConvert(customer.thirtyAndOneThirdYN)],
     thirtyYN: [this.utilService.YNConvert(customer.thirtyYN)],
     earnedIncomeExpenseType: [customer.earnedIncomeExpenseType],
     earnedIncomeExpense: [customer.earnedIncomeExpense],
     dependentCareExpense: [customer.dependentCareExpense]
     }));
     const customerFormArray = this.fb.array(customerFGs);
     this.trialBudgetForm.setControl('clients', customerFormArray);
}
```

for demo purpose, i didn't post the entire ts file, coz there are almost 600 lines. But i can provide more detail if needed. 
here's the html page (also only a snippet)

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="trialBudgetForm" (ngSubmit)="save(trialBudgetForm)">
<div class="settingsPage-box">
      <h3 class="box-border-bottom">Earned Income
        <span class="float_right add-field add-margin hand" (click)="addCustomer()">
          <i class=" fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg plusIconColor"></i>
          <span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Add Earned Income
          </span>
        </span>
      </h3>
      <div formArrayName="clients">
        <div *ngFor="let earnedIncomeCustomer of clients.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" class="row-view box-border-bottom">
          <div class="box-border-bottom row-view">
            <div class="col-sm-3 padding0">
              <label for="customer{{i+1}}" class="pushDown">Customer {{i+1}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 grid-block padding0">
              <div class="col-sm-1 float_right" (click)="deleteCustomer(i)">
                <span class="delete-row hand">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label class="pushDown">Earned Income</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 grid-block">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 u-justifyEnd">
                  <span class="add-margin float-left hand" (click)="addEarnedIncome(i)"><i class=" fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg plusIconColor"></i><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Income</span></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row grid-block pd-left amount-grid" formArrayName="earnedIncomes" >
                <div class="row-view" *ngFor="let earnedIncome of earnedIncomeCustomer.controls.earnedIncomes.controls; let j = index"
                  [formGroupName]="j">
                  <div class="col-sm-5 padding5">
                    <span class="label-type" *ngIf="j==0">Type</span>
                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="type" (change)="checkForDuplicateEarnedIncomeType(this.trialBudgetForm.controls.clients.controls[i].controls.earnedIncomes.controls[j].value.type)">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let optionEntity of this.constantsService.getDropDownFromLookup(this.constantsService.getText('EarningType'))"
                        value="{{optionEntity.lookupBean.code}}">{{optionEntity.lookupBean.longLabel}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 pd-left padding5 amount-bg">
                    <span class="label-type" *ngIf="j==0">Amount</span>
                    <div class="search-container">
                      <input (keypress)="this.customValidatorsService.validateNumberOnly($event)" formControlName="amount" class="form-control amount-input search-box"
                        placeholder="$0.00" currencyMask [options]="{ allowNegative: false,prefix: '$',hundreds: ',' }" maxlength="12"
                        (keyup)="calculateTotalIncome(earnedIncomeCustomer, i)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-1 pd-left">
                    <span class="label-type" *ngIf="j==0">&nbsp;</span>
                    <span class="delete-row hand" (click)="deleteIncome(earnedIncomeCustomer, i, j)"> <!-- G.S Income.controls.amount -->
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-view">
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <span class="total-info text-right">Total Earned Income</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 pd-left amount-bg">
                    <span class="total-info text-right">${{ earnedIncomeCustomer.totalEarnedIncome | number : '1.2-2'}} 
                    </span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-view">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span *ngIf="duplicateEarnedIncomeType" class="red-font-color">Choose a different use type</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="box-border-bottom row-view">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label class="pushDown">Earned Income Options</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 grid-block">
              <div class="col-sm-5 form-group label-check display-check">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" formControlName="thirtyAndOneThirdYN">
                <label for="check-1">30+1/3</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 form-group label-check display-check">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-2"  formControlName="thirtyYN">
                <label for="check-2">$30</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-border-bottom row-view">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label class="pushDown">Earned Income Expenses</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 grid-block">
              <div class="col-sm-5 form-group padding_right">
                <div class="control-label">Type</div>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="earnedIncomeExpenseType">
                  <option value="-1">Select</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let optionEntity of this.constantsService.getDropDownFromLookup(this.constantsService.getText('EIexpenseType'))"
                        value="{{optionEntity.lookupBean.code}}">{{optionEntity.lookupBean.longLabel}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 padding0 padding_custom">
                <div class="control-label">Amount</div>
                <input formControlName="earnedIncomeExpense" currencyMask (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" class="form-control" [options]="{ allowNegative: false, prefix: '$',hundreds: ',' }"
                  placeholder="$0.00" maxlength="10" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="row-view">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label class="pushDown">Dependent Care Expenses</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 grid-block">
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="control-label">Expenses</div>
                <input (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" currencyMask formControlName="dependentCareExpense" class="form-control" maxlength="10"
                  placeholder="$0.00" [options]="{ allowNegative: false, prefix: '$',hundreds: ',' }" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I have been trying to debug this for couple days now. The issue happens after constructor executed and before ngOnInit was called. this error only occur when I added more than one customer, and come back to this page. (adding customer won't cause any problem, only when I comeback to this page that's when the error `this.validator is not a function` is shown.

It's strange because the error happen between constructor and ngOnInit, and populateData is called in ngOnInit, which means error occured before the page know how many customers will I load. But if only the error occur because I add more than one customer, it seems that applicaiton has to get that info within constructor, in which i didn't load the data yet.

Update 1: Sept 25 3:39PM EST
updated with populateData function

Update 2: full stack error: Sept 25 4:09PM EST

```
TrialBudgetComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: this.validator is not a function
at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.es5.js:2645)
at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.es5.js:2613)
at new FormControl (forms.es5.js:2936)
at FormBuilder.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormBuilder.control (forms.es5.js:5780)
at FormBuilder.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormBuilder._createControl (forms.es5.js:5822)
at forms.es5.js:5804
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at FormBuilder.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormBuilder._reduceControls (forms.es5.js:5803)
at FormBuilder.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormBuilder.group (forms.es5.js:5762)
at TrialBudgetComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/trial-budget/trial-budget.component.ts.TrialBudgetComponent.toFromGroup (trial-budget.component.ts:102)
```

Update 3 question closed: thanks to @yurzui's comment
I just realized that the architecture is messed up for this page. This component has a parent which only has (current component selector) in its template. The two component has exactly the same name just under different folder. The parent is at /trial-budget and children is at /trial-budget/trial-budget-main. The TrialBudgetComponent.toFromGroup is actually a function inside the parent. For some reason, it's being called inside ngInit instead of constructor. Still haven't figure out why error only happen with 2 customer. 
But lesson learned: 
1. read error message carefully especially first and last couple lines. I didn't read the last line. 
2. always construct form inside constructor and populate data inside ngOnInit()

Comment: is the error happening within the ngOnInit() or before that? Also, could you please show your populateData() method and any other life-cycle hook implementations within this component?

Comment: The error happening before ngOnInit(); onInit is the only life-cycle hook that I used @amal

Comment: Can you add full stack of the error?

Comment: right, sorry. I just added the full error message @yurzui

Comment: Add also `TrialBudgetComponent.toFromGroup` function

Comment: OMG, thank you for the great question. Just realize the strangest architecture I will elaborate in the question @yurzui